# Summernote Special Char Button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, summernote

1. I want to add a custom button to Summernote WYSIWYG editor.
2. This button will popup a little window containing special characters like: alpha - beta - degree etc.

I have look everywhere but was not able to find anything about this.
A hand would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by *little window*? Would it be a [dropdown listing](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1611) or a kind of modal/popup?

Comment: Just like a modal window. similar to one in http://fiddle.tinymce.com/sGfaab/1

Answer (score 5):

You have to create a plugin file.
[This](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/blob/develop/plugin/specialchars/summernote-ext-specialchars.js) could be a good starting point. It already have some special chars. To use it add 'specialchars' to the toolbar.

Comment: Good point finding the bug.
You know why when I use the `&le;` it replaces by `=` ?

Comment: If it happens when you type the character in the editor (instead of when you visualize text that has already been persisted), then I have no idea